# NSNotification not working on Swift translation (from Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

After converting my Objective-C code to Swift, I cannot get my NSNotifications to work. After an hour of searching in the web, I finally gave up. Consider the following example:

```
func getToUrl(url:String, timeoutInterval:Float) -> Bool {

    println("Starting HTTP GET to: \(url)")

    // Fire a notification
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("StartNotification", object: self)

    [...]

}

func getJsonFromServer() {

    // Add an observer which should fire the method test when desired
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "test:", name: "StartNotification", object: self)

    // Calls the function 
    getToUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com", timeoutInterval: 10)

}

func test(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("I am here!")
}
```

I cannot find the error, I would really appreciate if someone else could!

The code runs, but the test method is never called.

Comment: Have you tried removing the "object:" parameter from both methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in this, self to nil (in order to hear all objects)

```
func getJsonFromServer() {

// Add an observer which should fire the method test when desired
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "test:", name:   "StartNotification", object: nil)

// Calls the function 
getToUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com", timeoutInterval: 10)

 }
```

Comment: I have tried "nil" first and my app crashed, that is why I did not try it anymore. But now it seems to work, so most likely I have made a mistake before. It works, thanks!

Comment: When you add self (to object:),  your viewController says: I want hear "StartNotification" when I say it. When you add nil,  your viewController says: I want hear "StartNotification" when anyone says that.

Comment: Also after Swift 2.2, syntax for `"test:"` has been deprecated. You need to use `#Selector(self.test(_:))`